# CAML query - examine Contents column used in freetext predicate

Tags: search, caml-query

In my query I use the freetext predicate:

```
and freetext(Contents, 'my search string')
```

I'm getting some unexpected results from this search, namely the documents contain no relevant content, yet are getting returned.  I would like to return this `Contents` field used by the predicate to examine what it contains.  Just putting it in the select columns:

```
select filename, path, fileextension, author, lastmodifiedtime, site, Contents from scope()
```

throws a SOAP exception:

> Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.

This query runs fine when the `Contents` column is not selected for return.  **How can I examine the `Content` column of the returned results?**

Here is my total query:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
    <Query>
        <SupportedFormats>
            <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format> 
        </SupportedFormats>
        <Context>
            <QueryText type="MSSQLFT" language="en-us">select filename, path, fileextension, author, lastmodifiedtime, site, Contents from scope() where IsDocument= TRUE and contentclass = 'STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary' and (fileextension != 'dotx' and fileextension != 'dot' and fileextension != 'dotm' and fileextension != 'xltx' and fileextension != 'xlt' and fileextension != 'xltm' and fileextension != 'potx' and fileextension != 'pot' and fileextension != 'potm' and fileextension != 'accdt' and fileextension != 'vst') and (Site = 'http://my.sharepointsite/personal/somedocumentlibrary')</QueryText> 
            </Context>
        <Range>
            <StartAt>1</StartAt> 
            <Count>500</Count> 
        </Range>
        <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming> 
        <TrimDuplicates>false</TrimDuplicates> 
        <IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>true</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery> 
        <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior> 
        <IncludeRelevanceResults>true</IncludeRelevanceResults> 
        <IncludeSpecialTermResults>false</IncludeSpecialTermResults> 
        <IncludeHighConfidenceResults>false</IncludeHighConfidenceResults> 
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Answer (score 0):

To search within the document, you dont need specify content as a selected column. Simply write

```
SELECT column1,column2, column3
FROM scope()
WHERE FREETEXT('my search string')
and column1 = 'something'
```

---

If you want to use freetext (or contain) against column ie title etc, you can specify column name in query

```
FREETEXT([<full-text_column>,]'<contains_condition>')
```

But if you want to use it against document content, you dont need to specify it.
The full-text column reference is optional. For relevance purposes, MSDN recommend that you specify DEFAULTPROPERTIES here. For example:

```
WHERE FREETEXT(DEFAULTPROPERTIES, 'computer software')
```

will searches for documents that contain the search terms "computer" and "software".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That is not what I asked though - the search is finding false positives on results and I would like to know why.  Exactly the same results are returned whether `Content` is specified or not.  `DefaultProperties` is no good either - I only want to search content, not metadata.